# How can I extract a field from JSON-like text by name instead of by a fixed column?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, sed, cut

I want to extract a substring from a text file line by line. The info I needed is under a specific field. For example, I have the following text:

```
{name:x, version:1.0, info:"test", ...}
{name:y, version:0.1, info:"test again", ...}
{name:z, version:1.1, info:"test over", ...}
```

I've tried to use the following command to extract all versions:

```
cut -d',' -f 2 <file name> | cut -d':' -f 2 > <output>
```

This is not perfect. This works on the sample above, but if I have the following entry:

```
{name:x, info: "test", ..., version:1.2, ...}
```

the above command would report the incorrect versions. Is there any way we could extract the info based on the field name rather than by column?

The expect result:

```
1.0
0.1
1.1
1.2
```

Comment: Do you have random `:` and `=` in input as field separator?

Comment: @eleven,show the expect result ?

Comment: Sorry, I miss typing, all should be ":"

Comment: great, all answers are working. there should be 3 answers more for eleven.

Answer (score 4):

Using this `awk`:

```
awk -v f='version' -F ' *[{}:=,] *| +' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($(i-1)==f) 
   {print $i; break}}' file
1.0
0.1
1.1
1.2
```

Answer (score 4):

### Use Grep with PCRE to Extract Field Data

If you have pcregrep installed, or your grep has been compiled with [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) support, you can grep for the field you want. For example:

```
# grep with PCRE support
$ grep -Po 'version:\K[^,}]+' /tmp/corpus
1.0
0.1
1.1
1.2

# pcregrep doesn't need the -P flag
$ pcregrep -o 'version:\K[^,}]+' /tmp/corpus
1.0
0.1
1.1
1.2
```

Either way, you start the match by finding the *version* field, throwing away all consumed characters with `\K` so that the match only captures the field data, and then matching anything except a comma or closing brace. The -o flag tells grep only to print out the resulting match, rather than the whole line.

### No PCRE in Your Grep? Just Use Perl

If you don't have Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) compiled into grep, you should still have Perl itself because it's part of the [Linux Standards Base](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Languages/LSB-Languages/book1.html). Using Perl:

```
# NB: Avoid speed penalty for $& when perl > 5.10.0 && perl < 5.20.0.
# Use $& and remove the /p flag if you don't have (or need) the
# ${^MATCH} variable.
$ perl -ne 'print "${^MATCH}\n" if /version:\K[^,}]+/p' /tmp/corpus
1.0
0.1
1.1
1.2

# Use the $& special variable when ${^MATCH} isn't available, or when
# using a version without the speed penalty.
$ perl -ne 'print "$&\n" if /version:\K[^,}]+/' /tmp/corpus 
1.0
0.1
1.1
1.2
```

Comment: will match the `oldversion 1.2` too ;)

Comment: @jm666 Not part of the corpus. There are always edge cases. One could add `\b` or `\s` to the start of the match if you need to refine it further, but it is just clutter with the OP's given example. YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU `grep` for `-P` (PCRE Regex) and `--only-matching` option you can do:

```
$ cat file
{name:x, version:1.0, info:"test", ...}
{name:y, version:0.1, info:"test again", ...}
{name:z, version:1.1, info:"test over", ...}
{name:x, info: "test", ..., version=1.2, ...}
$ grep -oP '(?<=version.)[^,}]+' file
1.0
0.1
1.1
1.2
```

We use `version` followed by `.` (that matches any character) with a positive look behind assertion (`?<=`) and print everything up to a `,`.

Answer (score 1):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/.*version:\([^,}]*\).*/\1/' file
1.0
0.1
1.1
1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

sed again

```
sed 's/^.*version://; s/[,}].*//' < file
```

1.0
0.1
1.1
1.2

Answer (score 1):

This perl

```
perl -nE 'say $3 if m/^\s*{ (([^"]|"[^"]*")*)* \bversion\s*:\s* ([\d.]*)/x'
```

will

- **not** match the `version:2.2` inside of quotes,
- **not** match strings like `oldversion:1.2`

so for the following input:

```
{name: a, version: 1.1, info: "the version: 9.1 is better", oldversion: 0.1}
{name: b, version: 1.2, oldversion: 0.2, info: "the version: 9.2 is better"}
{name: c, info: "the version: 9.3 is better", version: 1.3, oldversion: 0.3}
{name: d, info: "the version: 9.4 is better", oldversion: 0.4, version: 1.4}
```

will print

```
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.* version://;s/[^0-9.].*//' YourFile
```

Assuming version number are using only dot and digit and no internal value content `version:`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
[root@giam20 ~]# cut -f2 -d "," sample.txt | cut -f2 -d ":"
1.0
0.1
1.1
```